# Windows Phone 8 Application Enrollment Token - How to uninstall

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mdm, in-house-distribution

If I create an [Application Enrollment Token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735576%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), I will get an aet and aetx file. The aetx file can be send to the phone via mail or can be opened in the web browser and will be installed then. However, I'm unable to uninstall the certificate. There is no option in the phone's settings or during the installation of an aetx.

Is there any way to uninstall a manually installed AET, except resetting the phone to factory settings?

AFAIK there is also no way to see or get extended information like the validation dates of the AET, except you've installed it via a MDM solution. So did any of you succeeded in deletion of the AET manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done manually! Microsoft says:

After a user enrolls a phone for company app distribution manually by tapping an AET.aetx file on their phone, the phone is automatically enrolled for as long as the certificate is valid (one year). After enrolling for company app distribution by this process, users cannot unenroll their phone by using the phone UI.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

However if you use the MDM Api to enroll a Phone (like Intune does), and unenroll that phone (either remote or manually) the aet is removed, too.

Comment: Hm sad to see that it is not possible like one can do under iOS, but thanks for your efforts!